# use initrd to fastest boot time

Tags: raspbian

i want boot my raspberry pi very fast (about 5sec) ...

i search in internet and read very solution that but none of them can Convince me ...

in official raspberry pi forum a moderator refer to initrd that can speed up boot time very fast ...

[image]

but i dont know how create and use initrd to boot from and use ..

please help how can i create and use initrd in raspbian to speed up boot time .

Comment: What do you mean by boot?  From power on to actually running a Linux use program takes 45 seconds on my Pi.  Some people claim less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if someone who identifies himself as "Raspberry Pi -- Director of Software Engineering" says something, presuming that refers to the organization itself, there is probably some truth in it.

I haven't used BerryBoot, so I can't say if it is 5 seconds, but there is a bit of a caveat here in that BerryBoot is a minimal operating system that's really a glorified bootloader.  You use it to then initialize something else, and that initialization is going to add a lot more than 5 seconds.  All by itself it is not good for much else.

It's also worth considering that a suggestion from a "Director of Software Engineering" may not necessarily be something that is easily implemented by just anyone following a quick recipe, and that is the case here.  An initrd (initial ramdisk -- but see footnote 2 regarding nomenclature) is a preliminary, in memory root filesystem loaded by (or potentially, inside of) the kernel.  They (or more properly, their close cousin `initramfs`) are used on normal linux distros, not to increase boot speed (they don't), but so that a variety of hardware drivers can be made available before the real root filesystem is mounted.  This is necessary because such kernels are intended to work on a wide variety of hardware, and drivers are needed *in order to mount that root filesystem from the hardware* -- but the kernel does not know which ones until it has examined the system.  It cannot simply have all of them built in because they conflict with one another.  I.e., this is a way for a generic kernel to adapt itself to circumstances.

This isn't used on the pi because the pi kernel is built from a forked source tree that is only for the pi.  Pi kernels aren't used anywhere but the pi, so they don't need to figure out what drivers are needed to mount the root filesystem and then load them as appropriate -- the appropriate ones are built in, and optional drivers can be loaded from the SD card once the root filesystem is mounted.

Using an initrd to create a fast boot would amount to the same thing as creating an extremely minimal system (e.g, with [busybox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox)).  The filesystem in there has to be very small -- it's going to be loaded completely into RAM.  This potentially makes it a worse idea than just using a small partition on disk, if it is going to significantly restrict the amount of RAM left over for actually running the system.

In short, although I could not read the rest of that thread because you did not include a link, I think what Mr. Hollingworth is discussing here is a specialized context (of course, you are also free to ask for more details there directly).  You *could* do this with normal raspbian, etc., but in the end you would not really save any time.  You would boot the initrd in 5,<sup>1</sup> but then the distro's [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) system would still take 30-40 more seconds doing it's thing.  Without that, the system won't work properly.

**In any case, describing how to create an initrd is well beyond the scope of a simple Q&A.**  If you search around online for "linux initrd",<sup>2</sup> I'm sure you'll find various tutorials and how-tos; you can start there, and then if you have *specific* questions about *some detail* of the process, feel free to ask.  However, most such questions would be off-topic here as they won't really be about the pi -- they'll be about linux, and as such you should use the [Unix and Linux Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

---

<sup>1.  If you look in the logs/`dmesg` on a normal pi, this is probably about the time it takes to get the root fs mounted read-write and start doing the most intensive init related things</sup>

<sup>2. The more proper and specific term now-a-days is **initramfs**, to prevent confusion between new and old methodologies ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603104/the-difference-between-initrd-and-initramfs) for more about that).  This difference isn't very significant to the above discussion.</sup>